# saving the result in array for preg_replace

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, preg-replace

i need to make $with in Array to use it in preg_replace ??

```
foreach($matches[0] as $match) {
$sql = "insert into url values('$id','$match','$shorturl')";
mysql_query($sql,$con);
$with="<a href=\"http://127.0.0.1/url1/". $shorturl ."\">http://127.0.0.1/". $shorturl ."</a>";
 } 
$html_links = preg_replace('"\b(http://\S+)"',$with , $_POST['url']);
```

any help ?

Comment: -1 because of the poorly formulated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to use `preg_match_all()`, to save the results in an array. Example:

```
preg_match_all("e( |s)", "the matches", $matches);
```

`$matches` will contain all the matches.

Look in the documentation for more details: 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

---

EDIT: If you want to save the $with in an array, use the following:

```
foreach($matches[0] as $match) {
// $sql...
// mysql...
$with[] = "<a href=\"http://127.0.0.1/url1/". $shorturl ."\">http://127.0.0.1/". $shorturl ."</a>";
 } 

for ($w in $width) {
   // do something nice with each width, using $w
   $html_links = preg_replace('"\b(http://\S+)"',$w, $_POST['url']);
}
```

Comment: i used it before foreach  .. preg_match_all( $pattren, $urlinput, $matches); but i forget to write it

Comment: And what went wrong? You didn't get any matches or the wrong results? If you change the input after you try to match against a pattern, you will of course get different matches. Make the question clearer if you want more info, I can't guess everything.

Comment: i want to save the $with in array ! that's it ... simple :)

Comment: @maj, Hidde just showed you how to make `$with` an array as you retrieve the results of your query. If you want a more specific answer, edit your question to be much more specific.